# Retrieve all dates last week in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Is there a way to get **all** dates from the past week with mysql, even when they don't contain any records?

Now I have a query that looks something like this (for an app that can monitor working times etc):

```
SELECT user_id, SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( checkout_time ) - TIME_TO_SEC( checkin_time ) ) AS total_time, DATE( checkout_time ) AS checkout_day
FROM timetable
WHERE task_id = 19
AND checkout_time >= ( DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 1 WEEK ) )
GROUP BY checkout_day, user_id
ORDER BY checkout_day ASC
```

This works really well, but I "only" get the dates a user actually have been clocked in (which is really the days that matters). But what would be really great if there where a way to get all the dates in that one week interval. If something like:

```
DATE(INTERVAL 1 WEEK) as dates
```

would retrieve:

```
|dates
------------
|2012-07-15
|2012-07-16
|2012-07-17
|2012-07-18
|2012-07-19
|2012-07-20
```

Might not be what you usually use SQL for, but if someone knows a way – you would make my day.

Comment: See if this helps
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120648/search-for-available-dates-within-a-given-range-without-calender-table

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a static UNION for the 7 days, and left jon the rest on to them

```
SELECT
  user_id,
  COALESCE(SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( checkout_time ) - TIME_TO_SEC( checkin_time ) ), 0) AS total_time,
  week.day AS checkout_day
FROM (
   SELECT CURDATE() AS day
   UNION SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
   UNION SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY
   UNION SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY
   UNION SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 4 DAY
   UNION SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 5 DAY
   UNION SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 DAY
) AS week
LEFT JOIN timetable ON (task_id = 19 AND DATE(week.checkout_time) = week.day)
GROUP BY week.day, user_id
```

**notes**

1. all filters from timetable most be in the `ON` part, or you want see rows whit no timetable data.
2. mysql automaticly use the fields in `GROUP BY` as `ORDER BY` if you don't speify somthin else

Comment: That could work – however, what if I want to retrieve the past month istead of week using ( DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 1 MONTH ) ) all of a sudden? That would be a LOT of unions? =)

Comment: i have a special table with int values from 0 to 100, that i use for that: ``SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL `range`.nr DAY AS day FROM `range` WHERE day > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH``

Answer (score 0):

Since your date period is week, you can convert them into the nth week of the year to compare.

```
WHERE YEARWEEK(checkout_time) = YEARWEEK(DATE_SUB( CURDATE() ,INTERVAL 7 DAY))
```