# find longest duration between times

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am running a SQL query in SQL Server that pulls back a list of times. eg

```
00:01:45
00:01:55
00:02:25
00:05:33
00:10:45
00:11:01
00:13:45
```

I want to some how with SQL return a single time that represents to the largest duration between the times above (which is the output of a query). Is it possible to do this via SQL and if so, how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL: finding longest date gap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315262/sql-finding-longest-date-gap)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the analytic functions `LAG` or `LEAD` to do this. By performing a `DATEDIFF` calculation on either the previous or next row (ordering by the time) we can determine the duration between each ordered pair. The only thing left to do is take the `MAX`.

```
with Data as (
         select a.TheTime
              , DateDiff(minute, Lag(a.TheTime, 1, a.TheTime) over(order by a.TheTime asc), a.TheTime) as Duration
         from (values
             (Convert(time(0), N'00:01:45'))
           , (Convert(time(0), N'00:01:55'))
           , (Convert(time(0), N'00:02:25'))
           , (Convert(time(0), N'00:05:33'))
           , (Convert(time(0), N'00:10:45'))
           , (Convert(time(0), N'00:11:01'))
           , (Convert(time(0), N'00:13:45'))
         ) as a (TheTime)
     )
select Max(a.Duration) as MaxDuration
from Data as a;
```

Comment: To overcome the Null problem and hence remove the coalesce function, you may modify the Lag function to Lag(a.TheTime, 1, a.TheTime).